# Disabling wrapping on Text node

Tags: react-native

I've got some preformatted text which I want to display unwrapped and allow the user to scroll both vertically and horizontally.

A contrived example of what I've got:

```
<ScrollView>
  <Text style={{fontFamily: 'monospace'}}>
    Some preformatted text which I don't want to wrap
  </Text>
</ScrollView>
```

The problem is that the text wraps and you can only scroll vertically.

One change that gets halfway there is by changing the `ScrollView` to:

```
<ScrollView style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
```

Wrapping becomes disabled, however scrolling doesn't work after I've done that.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Have you found a solution for disabling text wrapping? I'm looking for something akin to `white-space: nowrap` in CSS.

Answer (score 21):

It'd be

`<Text numberOfLines={1}>Some text</Text>`

You can also use `ellipsizeMode` attribute to control how overlapping text will behave.

For more informations - check out https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html